# How to get the last input only in EditText? (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

For example, if user types "abc" in the EditText field, I just want to get the last character "c".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String last = yourEditText.getText().toString();
last = last.substring(last.length() - 1);

System.out.println("last character: " + last);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding DonGru's post, with another alternative of getting the last character

```
EditText et;
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
CharSequence s = et.getText();
System.out.println(s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

since `getText()` returns a `CharSequence` you can also use that for getting the last character:

```
EditText my; 
my = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
CharSequence myCharSeq = my.getText();
System.out.println(myCharSeq.charAt(myCharSeq.length() - 1));
```